# Backbone el undefined on page refresh or page load

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Why is the el undefined on a page refresh or page load? Is it because the el does not exict?

```
class ListView extends Backbone.View

    className: 'channels-list'
    el: '#main'

    initialize: ->
        console.log @el
        # undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element needs to be a tag name or element that already exists in the DOM. When a new view is created the [`_ensureElement` function is called](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html):

```
// Ensure that the View has a DOM element to render into.
// If `this.el` is a string, pass it through `$()`, take the first
// matching element, and re-assign it to `el`. Otherwise, create
// an element from the `id`, `className` and `tagName` properties.
_ensureElement: function() {
     //...
}
```

To avoid this place the script tag below the element tag or wait for the document load event, for example using jQuery:

```
jQuery ->
    class ListView extends Backbone.View
        className: 'channels-list'
        el: '#main'
        initialize: ->
            console.log @el
```

Or, as Vitaliy  suggested, rest `.el` in the `initialize` function.

Comment: Great, this did the trick, I just added it to my main app.js file and now it all works. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. If you define `el` it should be available in DOM structure

Inside `initialize` method you can [set element](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) again if it already exists in DOM:

```
@setElement $('#main')
```